# rsync result in a text file (transfer speed needed for >10 thousand files)

Tags: rsync, tee

I want to rsync many fairly large files. 
more than 10 thousand files, each of which is ~ 100MB taking a few to tens of seconds to transfer. 
I guess I can unlimit the terminal scroll back and just copy the rsync output with --progress option so that I know the rough speed of each file transfer.
But because it takes so long, I want to run rsync in tmux, and I don't want to change tmux scroll back infinite.

I tried redirecting to tee, but each files has multiple values making the redirected log unreadable. For example, a file has record at 0%, 30%, 60%, 90% and 100%. I just want the 100% value.
I could write a script to parse the tee log file to get only the final value of each file transfer.

I wonder if there is a better way (maybe using right combination of rsync options?).